# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, drop consecitive columns without listing them all

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know this functionality exists in SAS, but am not sure if it is in SQL.

Is it possible to drop columns in a table without naming them all?

For example, in SAS you can drop columns C through I with syntax similar to "drop C -- I" where the dashes represent any and all columns in between columns labeled by variables C and I.

Is it possible to do this in sql? I have a ton of fields that I want, so I want to avoid having to type each field into a select select statement for a new table.

Currently I'm using

alter table #tablename

drop column col1, col2, col3, etc...

Thanks!

Comment: This is not possible in SQL, although you can use dynamic SQL to come close.

Comment: As gordon linoff said, it is not possible. If you wanted to make a helper for it that used dynamic SQL then you could use the sys.columns table to workout all the column names. But this would be quite a bit of work if its just a one off task.

Comment: Dang. Thanks anyways guys, I'm pretty new to sql using dynamic sql sounds too far out of my skillset. Thanks for responding!